# Data uri in Email

Tags: java, html

```
"<html><img alt=\"Embedded Image\" src=\""+datauri+"\"/><h2>output</h2></html>"
```

this HTML tag displays only the output not the image,where am i going wrong or how to send data uri to mail using javamail.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the *right* syntax? `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>` eg: for a jpeg, `data:image/jpeg;base64,<base64_encoded_image_data_here>`

Comment: yes,am getting the image when i paste it in URL..